# TerraformApply.jsonOutputVariablesPath : The term 'TerraformApply.jsonOutputVariablesPath' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

TerraformApply.jsonOutputVariablesPath : The term
'TerraformApply.jsonOutputVariablesPath' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
I'm trying to output varaibles via terraform In azure devops but everytime i run pipeline
this happens . P.S i'm using self hosted agent

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: script: |
                $json = Get-Content $(TerraformApply.jsonOutputVariablesPath) | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json;
                            foreach($prop in $json.psobject.properties) {
                                Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($prop.Name);]$($prop.Value.value)")
                                
                            }
this is the powershell command which i'm using in my azure devops yaml pipeline..................................,........

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the version on the task.
I assume you are using V1.
Try using V3 for the apply.

I've opened an issue at
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-terraform/issues/83

Edit: I messed up the versions .

Comment: Thanks for help I managed to resolve this by installing the terraform in powershell then executing the terraformapply.json command